# Is sql server needed for run a vb.net windows form solution with Sql database as back end?

Tags: vb.net

I am using a vb.Net 2010 and sql server 2005..

I want to run a solution that is windows form to another computer....

There is No centralized server...

I want simple help that is as below..

I simply want a answer yes or no.. 
If yes then Y  it is needed and if no then Y it is not needed..

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly:

The simple answer is yes, if your app is written against a SQL Server database, you will need a SQL Server for it to run.  You app probably reads data from that database, and if there is no database there, it will probably crash when it tries.

However, it seems like you have SQL server installed on at least one machine, so if they're on the same network, you should be able to access that database from the other machine to make your app run.

(If you don't need to go with a full SQL server, check out [SQL CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact), which just runs from a file.  Other light/free databases are available..)